# Llamada a un método con parámetros vacíos en Python

Tags: python

Estoy implementando un método recursivo que comprueba si el *string* que le paso al método es o no un palíndromo.

```
  def recursivePal(self, string):
  if string==None or len(string)==1:
      return True
  else:
      n=0
      x=len(string)
      if len(string)==1:
          return True
      else:
          if string[n]==string[len(string)-1]:
              return self.recursivePal(string[n+1:x-1:])
          else:
              return False
```

Como veis tengo una comprobación cuando el campo es *None* (que creo sería el equivalente en java a cuando compruebo un *null*) pero me gustaría saber como puedo hacer una comprobación de que el campo esta vacío por completo, es decir:

```
print(l.recursivePal())
```

sin que Python me arroje el error:

```
TypeError: recursivePal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

¿Es esto posible?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varias posibilidades:

- Usar un argumento opcional con un valor por defecto:

  ```
  def recursivePal(self, string=""):
  ```

  ---

  ```
  def recursivePal(self, string=None):
  ```
- Permitir que el método reciba un número indeterminado de argumentos:

  ```
  def recursivePal(self, *args):
      if not args:
          print("No se han pasado argumentos")
      elif len(args) == 1:
          string = args[0]
          print(f"Se ha pasado un argumento: {string}")
      else:
          print("Se han pasado más de un argumento....")
  ```

Una observación, la forma apropiada de realizar la comprobación de si una variable está asociada a un valor `None`  se debe hacer usando el operador de identidad (`is`) y no el operador de igualdad/equivalencia:

```
if string is None or len(string) == 1:
```

esto se debe a que solo existe un objeto `None` en el intérprete (singleton), todas las variables que existan asociadas `None` apuntarán al mismo objeto. Las razones por las que `is` es preferible a `==`  en estos casos son varias, pero básicamente  `is` es mas eficiente y predecible.

Comment: Muchísmas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba.